# numpy.fromstring separated by any whitespace

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, io

I have a document¹ where an n-dimensional matrix is stored as:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8

9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

with the precise dimensions stored in meta-data.  The 4 and the 5 are separated by `\n`, *not* by .  However, `numpy.fromstring('1 2\n3 4', sep=" ")` *does* do what I want, despite the documentation suggesting otherwise.  I'm hesitant to rely on an implementation that differs from the defined behaviour.

Why do `numpy.fromstring("1 2\n3 4", sep=" ")` and `numpy.fromstring("1 2\n3 4", sep="\n")` give me the (desired) `array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.])`, and is there a more robust (as in: corresponding to documented/defined behaviour) with the same effect?

---

¹<sup>The document is an XML-file where the text of the lowest elements in the tree represents numeric data.  I have no control over this file format.</sup>

Comment: So the desired behavior is to get all the elements in a single array? not as a matrix?

Comment: `\n` counts as the `extra whitespace` that is ignored.  There isn't provision in this function for dimension metadata.

Comment: @AnandSKumar Yes. As long as I get all the elements, I can easily `.resize`.  The file-format I'm reading can contain arrays up to dimension 7, so it is flattened beyond dimension 3 anyway.

Comment: I'd suggest splitting the input into lines yourself, with something like `txt.splitlines()`.  That way you can count blank lines.  This function could still be used on individual lines.  Or you can use `[int(x) for x in aline.split(' ')]`.

Comment: @hpaulj Both work, of course.

Comment: Details on handling separators are found in `swab_separator` and `fromstring_skip_separator` functions in `numpy/core/src/multiarray/ctors.c`.  Study at your own risk. :)

Answer (score 0):

If what you got is what you wanted (meaning `array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.])` is the desired behavior) , then I believe this is explained in the documentation of [`numpy.fromstring`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html) , the section for argument `sep` -

> **sep : str, optional**
>
> If not provided or, equivalently, the empty string, the data will be interpreted as binary data; otherwise, as ASCII text with decimal numbers. Also in this latter case, this argument is interpreted as the string separating numbers in the data; **extra whitespace between elements is also ignored.**

(Emphasis mine)

`\n` in this case is considered *extra whitespace* and hence it ignored. Please note ignoring does not mean that the elements before and after it become a single one , they are still separate numbers . A similar example with `\t` .

```
In [16]: np.fromstring('1\t2\t3\t4', sep=" ")
Out[16]: array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.])
```

Comment: Yes, the `\n` or `\t` is *extra whitespace*, but `fromstring` splits between `1` and `2` even though the desired seperator `' '` *does not occur at all*.  Hence my surprise.  I've decided to rely on this for now assuming that the numpy people will not suddenly decide to change this behaviour.

Comment: I do not think they would change this behavior, I think its behaving correctly according to documentation, when you give `space` as the separator, extra whitespaces(including `\n` is considered as a single space.

Comment: I would interpret *extra whitespace* as at least 1 times the separator followed by whitespace, rather than zero times the separator followed by whitespace.  I agree when you say you don't think they will change this behaviour, though.

Comment: If you are uncomfortable with that, you can try using `numpy.loadtxt` , it treats newline separately, and it would convert `'1 2\n3 4` to `[[1,2],[3,4]]` .

Comment: It looks like it treats ' ','\n','\t', i.e. all white space, the same, including how it interprets the parameter.  Bascially it's meant to load a long list of numbers, not a pretty printed array.